# codeigniter form validation with anchor tag click

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, validation

I want to validate some form fields without submitting the form.

Here is my code if someone can help.

View:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name..." class="textfield">
<a href="javascript:void();" onClick="validateName();">
</form>
```

Script:

```
function validateName(){  

var first_name = $('.textfield').val();

$.ajax({  
url: "Eligibility/contAjax",
type: "POST",
data: first_name,
dataType:"json",
success: function(response){
var obj = eval(response);  
if(obj.error==0){  
console.log('Success');
}
else{  
console.log('Failed');
}
}
});
}
```

Controller:

```
public function contAjax(){  

// loading form validation library //
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required');


if($this->form_validation->run()== TRUE){  
echo json_encode(array('error' => 0));
}
else{  
echo json_encode(array('error' => 1));
}

}
```

It always returns error=1 and form validation is not working...

Comment: Where is the `countryOfBirth` input field?

Comment: It is updated...

Comment: I changed the rule but its not working :(,

Comment: Here is a tip, learn to use something like firefox's firebug and view what you are posting!

Comment: problem in `data: first_name` change to `data: {first_name : first_name}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested code... but should work ( he said with a grin )

```
function validateName() {
    var first_name = $('.textfield').val();

    console.log('first_name is ' + first_name); // Check it's getting this far
    $.ajax({
        url: "Eligibility/contAjax",
        type: "POST",
        data: {first_name: first_name},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.error == 0) {
                console.log('Success');
            }
            else {
                console.log('Failed');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So with the addition of the console.log you can easily inspect your value...

I am not a big fan of using capitals in urls ( only works on windows and can lead to tears on a linux / apache server ) so best to use lowercase.

Just to add some more debug to this the simplish way you could inspect what the server side sees you posting...

This is just a way to check your posted values ( using something like firebug or similar is far better...)

```
function contAjax() {
// loading form validation library //
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required');
    $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 0, 'first_name' => $first_name));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 1, 'first_name' => $first_name));
    }
}
```

And your JS would become...

```
function validateName() {
    var first_name = $('.textfield').val();

    console.log('first_name is ' + first_name); // Check it's getting this far
    $.ajax({
        url: "Eligibility/contAjax",
        type: "POST",
        data: {first_name: first_name},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.error == 0) {
                console.log('Success  - First Name = ' + response.first_name);
            }
            else {
                console.log('Failed - First Name = ' + response.first_name);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The trick is to know how to "see" what is happening which makes debugging these kinds of things of lot easier...

Hope that helps. Again this code is untested but shows the principal...